# Discord.js - Help command returns "undefined" when a command doesn't have aliases

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My help command, which returns info about a command, returns `undefined` when a command doesn't have aliases or usage properties.

My help command's code:

```js
const helpcommand = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .addField("Command name",
     `${command.name}`)
     .addField("Description",
     `${command.description}`)
     .addField("Aliases",
     `${command.aliases}`)
     .addField("Usage",
     `${command.usage}`)
     .setTimestamp()
     .setFooter(message.member.user.tag, message.author.avatarURL()); 
     message.channel.send(helpcommand)
```

I tried to add `||` to make it return `none` when there are no aliases or usage but it didn't work:

```js
const helpcommand = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .addField("Command name",
     `${command.name}`)
     .addField("Description",
     `${command.description}`)
     .addField("Aliases",
     `${command.aliases}` || "none")
     .addField("Usage",
     `${command.usage}` || "none")
     .setTimestamp()
     .setFooter(message.member.user.tag, message.author.avatarURL()); 
     message.channel.send(helpcommand)
```

Can anyone tell me how I could display `none` when there are no properties available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are string literals allowing embedded expressions. If `command.aliases` is `undefined`, `` `${command.aliases}` `` will convert it to a string `"undefined"`. As a non-empty string is a [truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) in JavaScript, it will pass it down to `.addField()` instead of `none`.

If you check the value inside the curly braces like this: `${command.aliases || "none"}` you check the value of `command.aliases` before it's converted to a string, and as it's `undefined`, which is a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), it falls back to `"none"`.

So you can check it inside the curly braces or you could even get rid of those template literals, as they are not needed:

```js
const helpcommand = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .addField("Command name", command.name)
     .addField("Description", command.description)
     .addField("Aliases", command.aliases || "none")
     .addField("Usage", command.usage || "none")
     .setTimestamp()
     .setFooter(message.member.user.tag, message.author.avatarURL()); 

message.channel.send(helpcommand);
```